# Non-causal filtering in signal post-processing

Tags: filter, signal-processing, delay

I have velocity signal that that is calculated from the derivative of a logged position signal. As the calculation is done in post-processing both previous and future samples are available. I wan't to improve the quality of my calculated velocity signal by filtering it. I can easily understand how for example a moving average filter can be done non casually by shifting the samples, i.e.

```
y(k) = (x(i-1) + x(i) + x(i+1))/3
```

But how does it work for more advanced filters, in signal processing I have worked with causal chebyshev, butterworth filters etc., does it make sense to apply this kind of filters in post-processing and shift the data in a similar way as for the moving average or are there other proper filters to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, filtering a signal with Chebyshev or Butterworth filter shifts the signal. This is known as the ["group delay"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_delay_and_phase_delay) of the filter: let φ(ω) be the filter's phase response, then the group delay is the derivative

τ_g(ω) = −dφ(ω)/dω.

The group delay is a function of frequency ω, meaning that in general *each* frequency might experience a different shift, i.e. dispersion.
For a [linear phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_phase) filter like the 3-tap moving average filter, this does not happen; group delay is constant over frequency.
But for causal IIR filters, some variation in group delay is unavoidable. For popular IIR designs like Chebyshev or Butterworth, the group delay varies slowly across frequency except around the filter's cutoff.

Like you said, you can advance the signal by some number of samples in post-processing to counteract the shift. Since group delay generally varies with frequency, the number of samples to advance by is a choice about where you want it to match best. Something like the average group delay over the passband is a reasonable place to start.

Alternatively, another way to address shifting is ["forward-backward filtering"](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/filters/Forward_Backward_Filtering.html). Apply the filter running forward, then again going backward. That way the shift introduced by the forward pass is counteracted in the backward pass. You can use [Matlab's filtfilt](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html) or [scipy.signal's filtfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html) to perform forward-backward filtering.